# NLua nuget package restore failed in VS 2017

Tags: nuget-package, class-library, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6.1, nlua

I am trying to create a .NET 4.6.1 Class Library an use this nuget package with it:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLua/

When I click install I get this message:

```
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ClassLibrary1'.
```

If I try the same install with a web application in the same solution, the install completes successfully.

Answer (score 8):

You are probably creating a "Standard" library, but if you want to add NuGet packages to it then you need to create a "Framework" library. At least that's how I got it to work.